# Sony ToF AR の AR Foundationを活用したToF ARアプリをTofARServerでデバッグできるようにしたい

Tags: unity3d

Sony ToF ARを使ってアプリの開発を行っています。

マニュアルの [4.4.2. AR Foundationを使用したアプリケーションのDebug](https://developer.sony.com/develop/tof-ar/development-guides/docs/ToF_AR_User_Manual_ja.html#_debug_ar_found) を参照して実行したのですが、うまくできませんでした。

自身のプロジェクトの問題があるのかと思い、GitHubで公開されているtof-ar-sample-arのsimpleARFoundationでやってみたのですが、カラーカメラの映像が出ませんでした。
Unity側のコンソールにて特にエラーメッセージは確認できていません。

Unityは、2020.3.36f1を使用しています。
携帯端末は、Samsung Galaxy S20+ 5G です。
何かわかることがありましたら、教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

私の環境ではカラー映像が表示されて正常に動作しているようでしたので試した手順を書きます。
参考になれば嬉しいです。

### 動作環境

PC: macOS 13.0.1, Unity 2020.3.36f1
端末: Galaxy S20 Ultra 5G (Android 12)

### ToF AR Server

1. https://github.com/satoshi-maemoto/tof-ar-server-arfoundation からUnityプロジェクトを取得。このリポジトリにはARFoundationConnectorの設定が行われたシーンが公開されています。
2. ToF AR v1.1.0 の Baseパッケージ、Handパッケージ、ARFoundationConnectorパッケージをインポート。
3. Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Target API LevelがLevel 30以下になっていることを確認
4. Build Settingsで Assets/DebugServer/Scenes/MainARFoundation.unity シーンがビルド対象となっていることを確認し、ビルド＆デプロイ。

### ToF AR Samples AR

1. https://github.com/SonySemiconductorSolutions/tof-ar-samples-ar からUnityプロジェクトを取得。
2. ToF AR v1.1.0 の Baseパッケージ、Handパッケージ、ARFoundationConnectorパッケージをインポート。
3. Assets/TofArSamplesAr/Startup/Startup.unity シーンを開く
4. HierarchyのTofArManagerのInspectorでサーバーへの接続設定を行う
5. Playする　　
   macOSでの初回Play時は共有ライブラリの実行許可確認が複数回あるので全て許可する

### 実行結果

[image]